# Assigning ref in react-konva

Tags: reactjs, react-konva

How do we assign ref to the stage or layer object. I am using react-konva. When I do console.log(stageE1), it says undefined.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'stage',
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      ref: stageEl, // not working
      onMouseDown: (e) => {
        // deselect when clicked on empty area
        const clickedOnEmpty = e.target === e.target.getStage()
        if (clickedOnEmpty) {
          selectShape(null)
        }
      },
    })
    stage.container().style.border = '1px solid grey'
    var layer = new Konva.Layer({
      ref: layerEl, // not working
    })
    stage.add(layer)
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not `react-konva` usage. You are using Konva API directly. If you do this, you probably don't need to use refs. But if you really want:

```js
var layer = new Konva.Layer();
// set ref
layerEl.current = layer;
```

If you use `react-konva`, then you should define components in React way:

```
import { Stage, Layer } from 'react-konva';


const App = () => {
  const layerEl = React.useRef();
  return <Stage><Layer ref={layerEl} /></Stage>;
};
```